# strange chart of memory usage in GCD

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, stackdriver, dataflow, google-cloud-stackdriver

i executed a job in Google Cloud Dataflow and now i'm seeing the result on StackDriver. I don't understand the memory chart. I used only 1 and after 3 worker but the scale of this chart is the order of TB to second. it is normal? or maybe the scale is GB? in the metrics of this job, also, in a precise instant that i saw, the value of actual memory was 45 GB, and it isn't in this chart and is much smaller. can someone explain me this chart?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Total memory usage time` is one of the [Dataflow metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-dataflow) used to measure consumption of computing capacity (system memory in this case). This is

> The total GB seconds of memory allocated to this Dataflow job.

Customers are billed for the consumed resources accordingly with the established [Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing) .

Memory consumption is measured in `GB-seconds`.  1 GB.s is 1 second of wall clock time with 1GB of memory provisioned. Compute time is measured in 100ms increments, rounded up to the nearest increment.

Since memory usage on the chart is a time-aggregated value, values expressed in `TB.s` can be converted into `GB.h` by dividing by 3600 s:

`1 GB.h = 3.6 TB.s`

The curve shape and Y-coordinate depend on the aggregation and alignment settings you use: `max` or `mean`, `1m` or `1h` alignment period, etc. For instance in case of a short peak load, the wide time window will act as a big denominator for the mean aligner.

Answer (score 0):

*Memory usage* (measured in GB or TB) and *memory usage time* (typically measured in GB hr or TB s) are different measurements.

The Dataflow UI gives the following explanation for memory time: "The total running time for all memory used by all workers associated with your job. For example, if your job used 3GB of memory for 4 hours, the total memory time is 12 [GB] hours."

Comment: Also note the difference between memory allocated and memory usage. I'm guessing the 45 GB figure you are seeing is the total memory allocated to your workers, at least some of which is likely to go unused at any given point in time.